# Background color gradient for entire document

Tags: color, backgrounds, gradient

Is anyone aware if it's possible to change an entire document's background to a fading color?

In other words, can you take silver and slowly fade it to white from left to right and have this same effect throughout the entire document? I understand I could probably take Inkscape, make an image and put a background image for each page. I cannot find anything native which works so far.

Note that this is for a normal `report` based document and not for a `beamer` presentation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The idea of putting an image in the background seems the only feasible one. Look at the packages `eso-pic` or `background` for how to do it.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 30):

```
\documentclass[x11names]{report}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \path [left color = Gold2,middle color = Gold2!30, right color = white] (current page.south west)rectangle (current page.north east);   % Adjust the position of the logo.
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have chosen a conspicuous color. You may choose any color of your choice.

Comment: @trentonknight: Glad it helped. Thanks are better conveyed by upvoting and accepting the answer (by clicking thegreen check mark below the votecount) that helped you most. That is the tradition followed here in TeX.SX.

Comment: @user11232 If I run "pdflatex" twice on your answer file I get the right color you exhibit above, but if I run "xelatex" twice only a 1/4 of the page is painted! Why is it so?

Comment: How to background this way just one page (the cover)?

Comment: Oh, I see: \usepackage[firstpage=true]{background}