# Change background colour for entire document

Tags: color

I would like to change total document background colour; for example to Yellow: 
I have used two packages:

```
\usepackage{colour}
\usepackage{xcolour}
```

But I am unable to get my output, is there any solution?

Comment: There's no `colour` or `xcolour` package. To the dismay of British TeX users, the American spelling is used in the names.

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but the best way to change the background color of an entire document is to print it on colored paper. :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [`pagecolor` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pagecolor) adds some page colour checking options to that provided by [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) itself, which may not be necessary:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pagecolor,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{pagecolor,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow!30!orange}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

It automatically loads `xcolor` if it's not loaded by default.

Answer (score 32):

There is no package `colour` but it should be `color`. Similarly `xcolour` is `xcolor`. BTW, you can use `\pagecolor{yellow!30}` to make pages yellow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext} %% to add dummy text
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow!30}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

For adding more fancy coloring [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82237/11232) may be a starting point.