# How do I reproduce this in latex?

Tags: color, backgrounds, standalone

This is what I'm trying to produce:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,12pt,preview,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{color}
\pagecolor{yellow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
Animation Test
\vspace{6pt}

\textbf{\huge 1}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I can't get the background colour to work, but it otherwise looks more or less as it should. I've tried other document classes but they all have their own problems, such as adding in a ton of extra features I don't want, or else other parts of the code don't work instead.

Could someone help me get it working?

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't work with `standalone` class, however, it does run okay with `article` class (of course, without adding any extra packages). May be something for you to check at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25137/how-to-change-the-background-color-only-for-the-current-page; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82498/change-background-colour-for-entire-document?rq=1

Comment: try removing the `preview` mode :) as if in `\documentclass[varwidth,12pt,margin=3mm]{standalone}`. May be that could help.

Comment: Thanks @Raaja. Removing ````preview```` worked. The documentation for ````standalone```` seemed to suggest I needed that to get the margins working correctly, but apparently not. Seems to be all fine now. :)

Comment: It's either `preview` or `varwidth` to get paragraph mode for the content. Using both might not do what you want.

Comment: @Raaja: Please post your comment as an answer then, so the OP can accept it. This concludes the question officially and removes it from the "unanswered list".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing the `preview` mode as in 
`\documentclass[varwidth,12pt,margin=3mm]{standalone}` should do the job. Whence, you could use this:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,12pt,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{color}
\pagecolor{yellow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
Animation Test
\vspace{6pt}

\textbf{\huge 1}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this very easily using `standalone` and `adjustbox`. Use the `stack` key to stack the text and number, the `margin` key for the margin and the `bgcolor` key for the background color. The `\strut`s are for the correct lineskip.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\adjustbox{stack,margin=3mm,bgcolor=yellow}{%
    Animation Test\strut\\[6pt]
    \huge\bfseries 1\strut}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With this solution you could also add an animation with different background colors:

```
\documentclass[12pt,multi=PAGE]{standalone}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,...,10} {%
\begin{PAGE}%
\adjustbox{stack,margin=3mm,bgcolor=yellow!\the\numexpr10*\n\relax}{%
    Animation Test\strut\\[6pt]
    \huge\bfseries \n\strut}%
\end{PAGE}%
}%  
\end{document}
```

[image]