# How to set left margin background to be gray?

Tags: color, margins, backgrounds

In LaTeX, how can I set a background color of the paper such that it has left margin as gray and the center and right part of the paper has background white?

Comment: There is a [Page color package](https://ctan.org/pkg/pagecolor) that may help as seen in this question [Change background color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82498/change-background-colour-for-entire-document)

Comment: A more complicated but powerful approach is to use tikz of tikzpagenodes and everypage.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple with `eso-pic`if you use the relevant parameters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\color{Gainsboro!40!Lavender}\AtPageLowerLeft{\rule{\dimexpr 1in + \oddsidemargin-\marginparsep\relax}{\paperheight}}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 \title{Colouring Left Margin}
 \author{Wassily Kandinsky}

\begin{document}

\marginpar{Some text}
\lipsum[1-4]

\marginpar{Some text}
\lipsum[5-8]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks good. I would like to be able to write text also to margins. So my idea is to write a CV using \usepackage[absolute]{textpos} such that I can write my text to the gray background and to the white background.

Comment: I've just tested a simple `\marginpar` and it works fine (the colouring  is only a background , and it can ve overwritten)I'm not sure you need  `textpos`: for the  right margin, you have the command `\reversemarginpar` if necessary, and anyway, eso-pic can take care of absolute positions. Take a look at the documentation for details.

Comment: I've updated my answer with two `\marginpar`s. Please see if the result corresponds to what you want.