# Can I remove background/page colour in LaTeX?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, color, texlive

Perhaps this is a bit odd, but I found this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82498/change-background-colour-for-entire-document) about changing the page colour, and this thing is easy, but I am curious about removing the colour, altogether, from a page.
In essence, setting it to transparent.
Is this possible?
Can LaTeX support RGBA or HEX + Alpha?

Comment: What do you need this for? Also, have you tried doing this with another tool. The only scenario in which I can imagine this being advantagious is when you're using LaTeX output to compose images in other software. Those image editors should have the option to turn the background transparent (I'm sure, e.g., imagemagick can do this).

Comment: There is no color to remove. The page is transparent by default.

Comment: If you accidentally changed the page background colour to, say, white, the `\nopagecolor` command sets it back to default transparent background if the driver supports it.