# Gradient background for Beamer slides?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, color, backgrounds, gradient

I'm trying to create a background gradient for a set of Beamer slides.  [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82206/5629) seems to be doing more or less what I want but the answer does not work for me.  If I paste the answer into a file I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \backgroundsetup 

l.4 \backgroundsetup
                    {
? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on bg.log.
```

The linked question also doesn't do quite what I want because I would like the gradient to start in the center. [I'm going for an effect like this](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/7).

I prefer answers using tikz since I have worked with that.

Comment: Have you loaded the `background` package? Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? For the shading like that you can use the `radial` shading and specify the `inner color` as well as the `outer color`.

Comment: I was trying to build the answer from the linked question.  I didn't think it was worth pasting the whole thing into my question as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With `beamer`, you don’t need the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package, the `\usebackgroundtemplate` macro offers the possibility to set the background.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usebackgroundtemplate{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [outer color = green!20, inner color = blue!10]
      (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\title{This is the title.}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```