# gradient flat design template in LaTeX for presentation

Tags: beamer, templates

Does anybody have a beamer template with the "gradient flat design" concept in overleaf?
And also I am looking for different colors for my sections in the presentation. I could not find any template which uses the same thing.
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this: https://deic-web.uab.cat/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index.html?

Comment: Does this help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137437/gradient-background-for-beamer-slides ?