# Vertical gradient color for background of one page

Tags: color, backgrounds, gradient

I want to type some text with XeLaTeX like this picture on one page. Sorry I don't have any good minimal code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\begin{document}
تقدیم به بهترین هم‌نشینم حضرت مولوی
\end{document}
```

[Link for "Yas" font](https://fontlibrary.org/assets/downloads/yas/6d496aade0637f6ff0aed373a19aa54a/yas.zip)
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, do you want Persian/Arabic text on a yellow gradient background?

Comment: Yes I want. Place of text isn't matter. Just I want the final code compile correctly like always with xelatex and xepersian package. Thanks a lot

Comment: Notice the xepersian package must be last package. Sincerely

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [fill, rectangle, top color=yellow, bottom color=white, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=\paperheight] (box) at (current page.north){};
  \end{tikzpicture}

تقدیم به بهترین هم‌نشینم حضرت مولوی
تقدیم به بهترین هم‌نشینم حضرت مولوی
تقدیم به بهترین هم‌نشینم حضرت مولوی
تقدیم به بهترین هم‌نشینم حضرت مولوی
\newpage
تقدیم به بهترین هم‌نشینم حضرت مولوی
تقدیم به بهترین هم‌نشینم حضرت مولوی
تقدیم به بهترین هم‌نشینم حضرت مولوی
تقدیم به بهترین هم‌نشینم حضرت مولوی

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want the gradient on every page then you can use the `everypage` package.

MWE, adapted from [Background color gradient for entire document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82206/background-color-gradient-for-entire-document):

```
\documentclass[x11names]{report}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\AddEverypageHook{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\path [top color = Gold2,middle color = Gold2!30, bottom color = white] (current page.north east)rectangle (current page.south west);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\settextfont{Amiri}
\begin{document}\Huge
تقدیم به بهترین هم‌نشینم حضرت مولوی
\end{document}
\begin{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @Marjin, do you know how can I set the strength of the colour? And how fast or slow it fades?

Comment: @ForgottenApe you can change the values for `top color`, `middle color`, `bottom color`. If you want a 'stronger' color then you can set the top color to be darker. If you want a faster fade then you can set the middle color to be lighter. See the [xcolor manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf) for explanation on how to mix colors like `Gold2!30`, particularly section 2.3.2 _Meaning of standard color expressions_ on page 16 and the examples in Figure 5 _Standard color expressions_ on page 37.